# How to make auto DPI scaling work for forms not built with InitializeComponent();?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dpi

This is a follow-up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546589/can-i-automatically-scale-a-form-for-dpi-without-it-getting-blurry/59546957), but I will include all the necessary information here. I was wondering whether there was a way to automatically scale apps for higher DPI settings, and it turns out there is. I currently implement this by adding app.manifest and activating the commented out part concerning DPI awareness, but I have also done this via SetProcessDPIAware() in the program's main method, which yielded the same result.

When I build a form using Visual Studio's Form Designer, when I run the program with a scaling setting of 125% the entire form is scaled up. However, when I build a form using a combination of lines like `Label xinputtext = new Label { Location = new Point(15, 20)}` in the form's class and `Controls.Add(xinputtext)` in the form's constructor method, only the text is scaled up, none of the controls are.

How can I design a form that is affected by automatic DPI scaling *without* using the Designer?

By request, here is a demonstration:

```
namespace Just_testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           Controls.Add(button1);
           Controls.Add(button2);
        }

        Button button1 = new Button { Location = new Point(13, 13), Text = "button1" };
        Button button2 = new Button { Location = new Point(13, 35), Text = "button2" };
    }
}
```

With Windows' display scale set to 100%, the top left corner of the screen displays as follows:
[image: 100% scale]

With Windows' display scale set to 150%, it displays as follows:
[image: 150% scale actual]

When instead of code, I use the Designer to place these controls, with Windows' display scale set to 150%, it displays as follows:
[image: 150% scale desired]

And that is as I would want it. Note that the issue is not that the text in the second image is too large: the text scales correctly, but I want the buttons and everything else (including locations, of course) to scale with it. And this does happen if you build the controls using the Designer.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the problem you are trying to solve. Please add some steps and a very minimal code to reproduce the problem, show the screenshots, and tell the expectation.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sure; added!

Comment: Designer doesn't do a magic. There are a few differences when you use designer or you don't use designer in your example. For `Form` is sets `AutoScaleDimensions` and `AutoScaleMode`. For `Button` is sets `Size`.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with this.SuspendLayout(); and this.ResumeLayout(false);, does it?

Comment: It seems as if nobody knows. I was not able to figure it out either, and will give up now, sorry. I was hoping to get it figured out so I could spare others effort, but in the time it cost researching this and experimenting with this I could have written the desired behaviour myself several times over.